# Finding the general solution of $\frac{dx}{xy^3-2x^4}=\frac{dy}{2y^4-x^3y}=\frac{dz}{2z(x^3-y^3)}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, partial-fractions

> Find the general solution of the equation:
>   $$\frac{dx}{xy^3-2x^4}=\frac{dy}{2y^4-x^3y}=\frac{dz}{2z(x^3-y^3)}$$

Comment: Please use Latex

Comment: Sorry what is latex

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You can follow my solution to a very similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421799/find-the-general-solution-and-the-particular-solution-of-the-first-order-partial/3426651#3426651).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects that questions include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3490793/edit) to add details.

Comment: Thank you very much, my dear brother

Comment: $$ A=xy^3-2x^4 , B=2y^4-x^3y ,C=2z(x^3-y^3) $$
$$\text{To find $( \phi )$ we choose $A_1 ,B_1$ and $C_1$ by lagrange multipliers $A.A_1+B.B_1+C.C_1=0$ }$$
$$(xy^3-2x^4 ).(\frac{1}{x})+(2y^4-x^3y)(\frac{1}{y})+(2z(x^3-y^3))(\frac{3}{2z})=0$$
$$A_1=\frac{1}{x} ,B_1=\frac{1}{y} ,C_1=\frac{3}{2z}$$
$$\int\frac{1}{x} + \int\frac{1}{y}+ \int\frac{3}{2z}= \int0$$
$$ln(x)+ln(y)+\frac{3}{2} ln(z)=c_1^*$$
$$ln(x.y.z^{(\frac{3}{2})})=c_1^*$$

Comment: $${e^{(ln(x.y.z^{(\frac{3}{2})}))}=e^{(c_1^*)} \to 
x.y.z^{(\frac{3}{2})}= e^{(c_1^*)} \to \text{ let $c_1=e^{(c_1^*)} $}\to 
x.y.z^{(\frac{3}{2})}=c_1^* \to
\phi_{(x,y,z)} =x.y.z^{(\frac{3}{2})}}$$
$$\text{To find $(\psi)$ we choose $A_2 ,B_2 and C_2$ by lagrange multipliers 
$A.A_2+B.B_2+C.C_2=0$}$$
$$\text{Please help me find a $(\psi)$ }$$

Comment: @YASEEN TARQ What you wrote as a comment is not a comment. If this is in relation with your original question please edit it into the question itself and explain why this is a part of the question. Define the symbols that you use. What is $\phi$ ? What is $\psi$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{xy^3-2x^4}=\frac{dy}{2y^4-x^3y}=\frac{dz}{2z(x^3-y^3)}$$
This is probably the Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs in order to solve the PDE :
$$(xy^3-2x^4)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+(2y^4-x^3y)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2(x^3-y^3)z \tag 1$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{xy^3-2x^4}=\frac{dy}{2y^4-x^3y}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}(\frac{2(\frac{y}{x})^3-1}{(\frac{y}{x})^3-2})\quad$ is an homogeneous ODE. The usual change of function is $y(x)=xu(x)$

$u+x\frac{du}{dx}=u\frac{2u^3-1}{u^3-2}$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{u^3-2}{u(u^3+1)}du$

$\ln|x|=\ln|u^2-u+1|+\ln|u+1|-2\ln|u|+$constant.

$\frac{1}{xu^2}(u^2-u+1)(u+1)=c_1$
$$\boxed{\frac{x}{y^2}\left((\frac{y}{x})^2-\frac{y}{x}+1\right)(\frac{y}{x}+1)=c_1}$$

A second characteristic comes from solving 
$\frac{\frac{1}{x}dx}{y^3-2x^3}=\frac{\frac{1}{y}dy}{2y^3-x^3}=\frac{dz}{2z(x^3-y^3)}$

Using wellknown properties of equal fractions : $\frac{\frac{1}{x}dx}{y^3-2x^3}=\frac{\frac{1}{y}dy}{2y^3-x^3}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{1}{y}dy}{(y^3-2x^3)+(2y^3-x^3)}$

$\frac{\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{1}{y}dy}{3(y^3-x^3)}=\frac{dz}{2z(x^3-y^3)}$

$2(\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{1}{y}dy)=3\frac{dz}{z}$

$3\ln|z|-2\ln|xy|=$constant
$$\boxed{\frac{z^3}{x^2y^2}=c_2}$$

General solution of the PDE, equation $(1)$, on the implicit form is $c_2=\Phi(c_1)$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary conditions not specified in the wording of the question):
$$z^3=x^2y^2\:\Phi\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\left((\frac{y}{x})^2-\frac{y}{x}+1\right)(\frac{y}{x}+1) \right)$$